# A word meaning "neither good nor bad" (or, neither good nor evil)

Tags: word-choice

I'm looking for a word that means something like "innocuous" or "harmless," but not quite. What I'm looking for is almost like the word "amoral" (except amoral isn't the right word because it means without morals).

Comment: Looks like you want a neutral word, yet we have no context.  Can you add a mock sentence to your question?

Comment: You could use the word "neutral."

Comment: 'without prejudice' is a term sometimes used to describe a neutral party. "un-phasable" ..or perhaps "inured"  (habituated to unpleasant or bad things) are other ways that might convey what you're hoping for.  It is a guessing game without context.

Comment: On which side of the line between negative and positive do you want the word to fall?

Answer (score 3):

You could use: [benign](https://www.google.com/search?q=benign%20definition&oq=benign%20de&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.4240j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

> (of a disease) not harmful in effect: in particular, (of a tumor) not malignant.

Benign is very commonly used in English to talk about something that might not necessarily be a nice thing (like a tumor not being nice, for example) but that is not particularly harmful either.

[indifferent](https://www.google.com/search?q=apathetic%20definition&oq=apathetic%20de&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.3662j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#dobs=indifferent): (has multiple meanings - this is one)

> neither good nor bad; mediocre.

Another link to [indifferent](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/indifferent?s=t)

[apathetic](https://www.google.com/search?q=apathetic%20definition&oq=apathetic%20de&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.3662j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8):

> showing or feeling no interest, enthusiasm, or concern.

Comment: Good answer and I upvote; but here in India (and probably elsewhere) 'indifferent' carries negative rather than neutral connotations, as does 'apathy.' Since OP is looking for *a word that means something like "innocuous" or "harmless," but not quite,* I think the most appropriate option in your list is *benign* which you should therefore move to the top, to convince readers!